# SQL Server using Parallel Plan for Cost less than 5

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, parallelism

I have a pivot query that uses a parallel plan even though the cost is less than 5.

The Cost Threshold for Parallelism is set to default of 5, and MAXDOP is 0.

```
SELECT Column1, Column2 Column3, Column4 AS Column5, Column6 Column7, Column8 Column9, Column10 Column11
        FROM (
              SELECT Column12,
                        Column13,
                        Column1
                FROM Database1.Schema1.Object1
             ) Object2 PIVOT( SUM(Column13) FOR Column12 IN (Column2, Column4, Column6, Column8, Column10) ) AS pvtScore;
```

Following screenshot shows the estimated subtree cost as 1.39.

I am wondering why the parallel plan was used when the cost threshold is at 5 for parallelism to kick in.

[image: NUTS]

Version: SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: The cost of the parallel plan is less 5, the cost of the serial plan is probably higher.

Comment: You are right!! Cost of serial plan was `6.72`.

Comment: There you go. That's confusing at first for most people.

Comment: Check this: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/11/sql-server-cost-threshold-for-parallelism/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be confusing when you're first looking at parallel plans. The thing to keep in mind is that the [cost based optimizer](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/04/28/query-optimizer-deep-dive-part-1.aspx) picks what it estimates will be the cheaper query to execute. It's not always right, but hey, it's [not rocket science](https://gradebuddy.com/doc/464072/sql-query-optimization?full=1).

As a simple example, here are two count queries. One is allowed to go parallel, the other is forced to run serially.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Posts AS p;

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Posts AS p
OPTION(MAXDOP 1);
```

Their [query plans](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hy-ddl4hM) have the information we need:

[image: NUTS]

[image: NUTS]

The serial plan costs 121 query bucks, and the parallel plan costs 69.